# Correct fingering for playing staccatto fourths on guitar

Tags: guitar, fingering

How should I play this phrase? It needs to be played at a fast tempo, so changing strings on 6th fret using 3rd finger does not seem economical. Should I practice this way (fingerings on top of each note)?

```
        1  2  4  3  3  4  4  
     E|----------------------- 
     B|----------------------- 
     G|-----------6--------7-- 
     D|--4--6--7-----6--7----- 
     A|----------------------- 
     E|-----------------------
```

Comment: Anyone knows why my tab doesn't display here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd use this fingering:

1 2 3 2 1 2 2

Or possibly this fingering, to avoid the slightly awkward bar of the second finger at the very end:

1 2 3 2 1 2 3

Comment: This fingering seems most adequate without additional context not being part of question. The other, 'barre' version might fit better in cases where first finger needs to stay at the same fret.

Answer (score 0):

I would either play it like @Adrian said, or 1 3 4 3 3 4 4 (pretty much what your tab says at the top)

If you can't work with fingers 3 and 4 that fast, you can use @Andrian's fingering.

But i would suggest practicing your 3rd and 4th fingers, because it's really likely to find a song that you'll need them to play fast, and you won't be able to use them

Also, a little tip: When you are trying to play fast, the fingers on the fretboard should be pressed slightly more lightly

*Update:*

> *changing strings* on 6th fret using 3rd finger seems not economical

You don't really need to *change* your finger. You can press both strings with the same finger,kinda like playing a two-note chord

Answer (score 0):

I have my guitar in my hand, and find it easiest to play 1 3 4 3 3 4 4.

That is:

- D string 4th fret with 1st finger
- pluck D string
- 3rd finger 6th fret, both G and D strings
- pluck D string
- without moving 3rd finger, 4th finger 7th fret, both strings
- pluck D string
- lift 4th finger
- pluck G string
- pluck D string
- replace 4th finger, again 7th fret of both strings
- pluck D string
- pluck G string